# Is there a way to get attached file properties?

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a media file attached to my Notes document. And here is my code to pull file size info:

```
RichTextItem body = (RichTextItem)COLL_DOC.getFirstItem("Body");
Vector atts = body.getEmbeddedObjects();

for (int i = 0; i < atts.size(); i++) {
    EmbeddedObject att = (EmbeddedObject)atts.elementAt(i);
    if (att.getType() == EmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT) {
        System.out.println(att.getFileSize());
    }
}
```

But I need to get media file length in seconds instead of file size in bytes. So is there an easy way to get video length or get attached file properties that shows video length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documantation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_WORKING_WITH_EMBEDDED_OBJECTS_JAVA.html) of EmbeddedObject just give filesize or you can extact the file to store it in local file system. If it is possible, you can get the duration by using [xuggler](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/xuggler/inspect-a-video-file-with-xuggler/) library.

Comment: i'ts not good idea to extract video files on Domino server.. especially because they are all >10Mb in size and there are >1K documents with attachments

Comment: On some Linux-based Domino servers, the /tmp folder will be a memory-based filesystem, so extracting to /tmp would be quite fast, and you could delete the file as soon as you were done so the memory use should not cause a lot of swapping.

Comment: Ok.. I could do it with xuggler. Thanks everybody